# Please i would like to know if my model is over fitted from the look of this graph

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting-underfitting

[click on this link to view image - Is there any over fitting from the look of this learning curve?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c7Gr.png)

Comment: Questions and Answer's should be explanatory without the  links. Because, it will become useless if page (that is associated with link) becomes unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

No model is not over fitted. If model is overfitted then validation won't improve but in your case it is improving